# Xamarin forms : How to center a video when scrolling (like tiktok)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I working on xamarin forms. I am displaying video tht I have looad on my carrouselView. I would like to center an item when scroolling up or down so that the user do not have scroll many to center a video.

Thanks for your help.

here is xalm code :

```
<CarouselView x:Name="VideosCarouselView"
 
  PeekAreaInsets="0"
  Loop="False"
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"

          >


<CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
<LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
               ItemSpacing="1"/>
</CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="0" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

     

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0"  x:Name="ParentGrid"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0">
       
     <xct:MediaElement  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"   Source="{Binding UserVideoBlobAdress}"   IsLooping="True" Margin="0" 
                       BindingContextChanged="OnMediaElementBindingContextChanged" Aspect="AspectFit"
                        
                        ShowsPlaybackControls="True" AutoPlay="False"  x:Name="MyVideoPlayer"   >

        <xct:MediaElement.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnVideoItemTapped" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
        </xct:MediaElement.GestureRecognizers>

     </xct:MediaElement>

 </Grid>

    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
</CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Comment: see the docs on [snap points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/scrolling#snap-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Jason said that you can use the [Snap points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/scrolling#snap-points).

You can add the `SnapPointsAlignment` to the CarouselView. You can set the SnapPointsAlignment to center.

Here is the code you can refer to:

```
<CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                           SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                           SnapPointsAlignment="Center" />
</CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
```